# Play message while recording

Tags: twilio

I am using Twilio to record phone calls for purposes of recording people's consent on an over the phone application for insurance.  All parties on the call are well aware they are being recorded.

I want to add the ability to play some standard .wav files about what the people are agreeing to.  I want those .wav played in such a way that is it also recorded with the main recorded so we just get one long recording with the customers consent and any interaction with the agent.

How can I do that?

I can't find any reference on how to do that on the Twilio on the API.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Twilio Studio using the [Call Recording Widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/call-recording). Make sure the call recording widget is not the first widget in the flow, as called out in the documentation (or you will get an error since the call needs to be answered before recording).

Once the Call Recording Widget is enabled (and recording), you can then use a [Gather Input on Call Widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/gather-input-call) to Say/Play the media file and collect their responses.